# Is there a way to check the version of a node module after importing or requiring it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to check the version of a module from *within* a script?

Based on my Python experience, I tried this:

```js
const someModule = require('some-module');
someModule.version
```

But no dice. Is there any other way to do this? I'm suspecting I'm not getting the version I thought I was and I'd like to check.

When searching all I get is people repeatedly instructing how to get a module's version on the command line.

Comment: If it is a module you installed yourself and that is in the package.json you could simply require the package.json file and get the version out of there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741373/check-package-version-at-runtime-in-nodejs

Comment: @TheProgrammer which `package.json`? What if the module is installed globally, locally, and/or as a dependency of another package? I'm trying to double-check which one is being imported.

Comment: That's a really tricky requirement. There is no simple .version property of a module. You would have to read the version from the package.json file. Look at the link I provided, that's a related question.

Comment: @TheProgrammer that link doesn't tell me how to verify which one `require()` chooses. The answer by @Keith has got it: `require.resolve()` is the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `require.resolve`, to get the directory of your module.
Then simply join the path from this with `package.json`, from this you can get the version.

eg..

```
const { dirname, join } = require("path");
const ver = require(join(
    dirname(require.resolve("react")),
    "package.json"
)).version;

console.log(ver);
```

Comment: Good luck if the entry point is not at the top level

Comment: @charlag  You can just parse the directory string and look for `node_modules`, and trim it there.  eg.  `/somepath/node_modules/react/src/entry.js`, you can then see it's `/somepath/node_modules/react/package.json`,..  Have you an example npm module, I could then test and update with?

Comment: After @charlag's unhelpful comment sent me down a rabbit hole, I wanted to share a solution: `require("react/package.json").version`.