# Enforce version of injected dependency in NPM module

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-injection

Main module X expects an injected dependency of module Y. Therefore, X does not have module Y in its dependencies (package.json). There was an incident when X was run and injected with an old version of Y, since it is incompatible.

What is the best practice for avoiding this kind of incidents? Validate by code the version of the injected module? How about deeper injections like module X injected with module Y injected with module Z, and X must require some minimum version of Z to be used in Y?

Comment: The **only** (portable) way is by specifying [a specific version number range](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions) in your `package.json` file.  But if you can guarantee that your `node_modules` directory will be present in your published/released builds at runtime (which implies that you aren't using a bundler/packer/tree-shaker/etc) you could use this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741373/check-package-version-at-runtime-in-nodejs